# DevTools persistence not taking effect even with mapped file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write some javascript in a mapped file trough Workspaces in Chrome 64.

I had a hard time making Chrome use the local file instead but after a manual map it's already there. But even with the mapped file, I edited the file, hit refresh and the console keeps saying error in line N and when I click it, it takes me to the persisted version of the files and the line (and the whole function) where the error is now gone but the error is still there.

It's like Chrome is still running the old version. I usually have a similar issue in which I have to close the tab and re-open it since "the Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" or clicking Shift + CMD + R doesn't load the new version. And old version is persisting cache and Workspaces but I can't figure where is this old version sticking.

I looked into the Application tab but there isn't any Service Worker or any other place where the old file would seem to be kept in until the tab is closed.

This is an angular app running over SalesForce but I'm loading just an iframe in the browser so most of the rest of the app complexity if left out. This is just one single view of the app that works fine running like a single iframe, so I don't think it has anything to do SF, maybe Angular.

Comment: Is it an HTML file? Are you editing it via the DOM Tree in the Elements panel?

Comment: No, DOM changes can't be persisted in Workspaces. This is a .js file and the weird part is that the console points to the local file but points to a line that it's not there anymore. It's like it references the local file but evaluates the code in the old one which I can't find where it is.